# iOS Binary Rejected, failed to launch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, binary

I've just had my app rejected for the second time for failing to launch. When I run the app on my iPhone 5 with the code signing identity set to iPhone developer the app runs without issue, however when set to Distribution I am prompted with a "No matching provisioning profile found" error.

If someone could shine some light on what my issue could be that would be great. A link to the error report is below.

[Error Report](http://pastebin.com/3AYxkpek)

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Many thanks,

Takz

Comment: Please include symbolicated crash log. The one you included isn't helpful. Moreover, provisioning profile is not a reason for app rejection. Please check at your side as standalone app. See where it crashes

Comment: you installed the distribution certificates in xcode?. provisioning file is not found for the current app. thats why its showing the error. create new provisioning file(distribution) and install it. then try.

Answer (score 0):

App is rejected, because it's getting crashed. Rejection has nothing to do with the selection of provisioning profile. As @iAnum said, you need to test the app at your end for that crash. Fix that and upload the binary again. Hope, Application will not get rejected then :)